# VBA - Multiple Checkboxes Assigned to Same Macro, How to Determine which Checkbox Fired Event?

Tags: vba, events, excel

I have about 20 checkboxes on an excel sheet. I want to detect when a checkbox is clicked and which checkbox is clicked.

I know I could make a method for each checkbox but this is definitely not the best way. So I assigned each checkbox to the same macro:

```
Public Sub fieldCheck_Click()
    MsgBox "checkbox clicked"
End Sub
```

How can I determine which checkbox fired the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at `Application.Caller` to get the name of the clicked checkbox, or you can pass one or more parameters in the OnAction setting: eg set the "macroname" to

```
'fieldCheck_Click "Item1"' (including the single- and double-quotes)
```

or

```
'fieldCheck_Click "Item1", 55'
```